# Append text to H1 tag that has wrapped onto 2 lines

Tags: css, word-wrap, html-heading

I have an `H1` tag and on the same line, immediately following the `H1` tag I have a link (inside a `SPAN`). I have both the `H1` tag and the `SPAN` tag set to `float:left` and they appear on the same line, which as how I want it.

However, in the occasional sccenario when the `H1` tag has so much text it wraps onto a 2nd line, the following `SPAN` tag (with link inside) no longer sits neatly behind the last part of the `H1` tag, but instead appears on the next line down.

```
<h1 style="float:left;">some really long text here ... blah</h1><span style="float:left;"><a href="">my link</a></span>
```

This currently renders like this...

> **some really long text here ...**
>   **blah**
>   my link

..but I'd really like it to appear like this...

> **some really long text here ...**
>   **blah** my link

How can I force it to always keep the SPAN (containing my link) directly behind the last word of the H1 tag, WITHOUT resorting to putting my link/span inside the H1 tag block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `h1` to `display:inline`, there's no need for `float:left` then either.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your H1 to `{ display:inline; }` and remove both floats.

Answer (score 0):

with a width for the h1 or position: absolute for span.
but for this you'll need to put h1 and span into a div container

Answer (score 0):

you can define the width of the `h1` and the `span`, it should work.